# Configure search to show particular cells of a list

Tags: list, web-part, search, search-results, formatting

This might be some kind of a stupid question, but I'm absolutely new to SharePoint and I've no idea what to do.

I uploaded a list to my SharePoint and added a search scope for it. Now I can search, but the results look like this:

> DispForm.aspx
>
> > Text of some cell ... text of the cell with the searched text
>
> http://[...]/DispForm.aspx?ID=whatever

This may work, but it doesn't look good. Is there an easy way to configure it to look like this?

> Title cell
>
> > Description cell; cell, the searched text was found in
>
> http://[...]/DispForm.aspx?ID=whatever